# SCSS: Alert Component - change the SVG color based on background color?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass, bootstrap-5

I want to change the Close Button SVG Color based on what color is used in background I'm using some Sass functions * ($_luminance-list, color-contrast, contrast-ratio, luminance) to control the colors.*

**Codepen example:**

[codepen](https://codepen.io/themes4all/pen/ExgPgZQ)

**Here is the Current result:**

[image]

**What I want to achieve:**

[image]

**My Full Code include the functions that I using.**

```
$_luminance-list: .0008 .001 .0011 .0013 .0015 .0017 .002 .0022 .0025 .0027 .003 .0033 .0037 .004 .0044 .0048 .0052 .0056 .006 .0065 .007 .0075 .008 .0086 .0091 .0097 .0103 .011 .0116 .0123 .013 .0137 .0144 .0152 .016 .0168 .0176 .0185 .0194 .0203 .0212 .0222 .0232 .0242 .0252 .0262 .0273 .0284 .0296 .0307 .0319 .0331 .0343 .0356 .0369 .0382 .0395 .0409 .0423 .0437 .0452 .0467 .0482 .0497 .0513 .0529 .0545 .0561 .0578 .0595 .0612 .063 .0648 .0666 .0685 .0704 .0723 .0742 .0762 .0782 .0802 .0823 .0844 .0865 .0887 .0908 .0931 .0953 .0976 .0999 .1022 .1046 .107 .1095 .1119 .1144 .117 .1195 .1221 .1248 .1274 .1301 .1329 .1356 .1384 .1413 .1441 .147 .15 .1529 .1559 .159 .162 .1651 .1683 .1714 .1746 .1779 .1812 .1845 .1878 .1912 .1946 .1981 .2016 .2051 .2086 .2122 .2159 .2195 .2232 .227 .2307 .2346 .2384 .2423 .2462 .2502 .2542 .2582 .2623 .2664 .2705 .2747 .2789 .2831 .2874 .2918 .2961 .3005 .305 .3095 .314 .3185 .3231 .3278 .3325 .3372 .3419 .3467 .3515 .3564 .3613 .3663 .3712 .3763 .3813 .3864 .3916 .3968 .402 .4072 .4125 .4179 .4233 .4287 .4342 .4397 .4452 .4508 .4564 .4621 .4678 .4735 .4793 .4851 .491 .4969 .5029 .5089 .5149 .521 .5271 .5333 .5395 .5457 .552 .5583 .5647 .5711 .5776 .5841 .5906 .5972 .6038 .6105 .6172 .624 .6308 .6376 .6445 .6514 .6584 .6654 .6724 .6795 .6867 .6939 .7011 .7084 .7157 .7231 .7305 .7379 .7454 .7529 .7605 .7682 .7758 .7835 .7913 .7991 .807 .8148 .8228 .8308 .8388 .8469 .855 .8632 .8714 .8796 .8879 .8963 .9047 .9131 .9216 .9301 .9387 .9473 .956 .9647 .9734 .9823 .9911 1;

@function color-contrast($background, $color-contrast-dark: $color-contrast-dark, $color-contrast-light: $color-contrast-light, $min-contrast-ratio: $min-contrast-ratio) {
  $foregrounds: $color-contrast-light, $color-contrast-dark, $white, $black;
  $max-ratio: 0;
  $max-ratio-color: null;

  @each $color in $foregrounds {
    $contrast-ratio: contrast-ratio($background, $color);
    @if $contrast-ratio > $min-contrast-ratio {
      @return $color;
    } @else if $contrast-ratio > $max-ratio {
      $max-ratio: $contrast-ratio;
      $max-ratio-color: $color;
    }
  }

  @warn "Found no color leading to #{$min-contrast-ratio}:1 contrast ratio against #{$background}...";

  @return $max-ratio-color;
}

@function contrast-ratio($background, $foreground: $color-contrast-light) {
  $l1: luminance($background);
  $l2: luminance(opaque($background, $foreground));

  @return if($l1 > $l2, ($l1 + .05) / ($l2 + .05), ($l2 + .05) / ($l1 + .05));
}

@function luminance($color) {
  $rgb: (
    "r": red($color),
    "g": green($color),
    "b": blue($color)
  );

  @each $name, $value in $rgb {
    $value: if($value / 255 < .03928, $value / 255 / 12.92, nth($_luminance-list, $value + 1));
    $rgb: map-merge($rgb, ($name: $value));
  }

  @return (map-get($rgb, "r") * .2126) + (map-get($rgb, "g") * .7152) + (map-get($rgb, "b") * .0722);
}

@function opaque($background, $foreground) {
  @return mix(rgba($foreground, 1), $background, opacity($foreground) * 100);
}

@function tint-color($color, $weight) {
  @return mix(white, $color, $weight);
}

@function shade-color($color, $weight) {
  @return mix(black, $color, $weight);
}

@function shift-color($color, $weight) {
  @return if($weight > 0, shade-color($color, $weight), tint-color($color, -$weight));
}

$white:          #ffffff       !default;
$black:          #000000       !default;

$min-contrast-ratio:   4.5                   !default;
$color-contrast-dark:  $black                !default;
$color-contrast-light: $white                !default;

$yellow: #ffc107 !default;

$theme-colors: () !default;
$theme-colors: map-merge(
    (
        "yellow":   yellow
    ),
    $theme-colors
);

@mixin alert-variant(
  $background,
  $border,
  $color: color-contrast($background)
) {
  color: $color;
  background-color: $background;
  border-color: $border;
  
  .btn-close {
      filter: invert(1) grayscale(100%) brightness(200%);
  }
}

@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
  .alert-#{$color} {
    @include alert-variant($value, $value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the `filter` on `.btn-close`, this part:

```
 //CSS Generated
.alert-yellow .btn-close {
  -webkit-filter: invert(1) grayscale(100%) brightness(200%);
  filter: invert(1) grayscale(100%) brightness(200%);
}

//SCSS
.btn-close {
  filter: invert(1) grayscale(100%) brightness(200%);
 }
```

#### Snippet

```css
.alert-blue {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #0d6efd;
  border-color: #0d6efd;
}

.alert-blue .btn-close {
  -webkit-filter: invert(1) grayscale(100%) brightness(200%);
  filter: invert(1) grayscale(100%) brightness(200%);
}

.alert-yellow {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffc107;
  border-color: #ffc107;
}


.alert {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.alert-dismissible {
  padding-right: 3rem;
}

.alert-dismissible .btn-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 1.7rem 1.6rem;
}

.btn-close {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  color: #000;
  background: transparent url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/PjxzdmcgZGF0YS1uYW1lPSJMYXllciAxIiBpZD0iTGF5ZXJfMSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDY0IDY0IiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPjx0aXRsZS8+PHBhdGggZD0iTTguMjUsMCwzMiwyMy43NSw1NS43NSwwLDY0LDguMjUsNDAuMjUsMzIsNjQsNTUuNzUsNTUuNzUsNjQsMzIsNDAuMjUsOC4yNSw2NCwwLDU1Ljc1LDIzLjc1LDMyLDAsOC4yNVoiIGRhdGEtbmFtZT0iJmx0O0NvbXBvdW5kIFBhdGgmZ3Q7IiBpZD0iX0NvbXBvdW5kX1BhdGhfIi8+PC9zdmc+) center/1em auto no-repeat;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-blue alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <p><strong>Note!</strong> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the and typesetting industry.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-yellow alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <p><strong>Note!</strong> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the and typesetting industry.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```